# How to make transparent color in BitmapData in flex

Tags: apache-flex, bitmapdata

I have a code like this:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
bitmapData.draw(this);
var ba:ByteArray = (new PNGEncoder()).encodeByteArray(bitmapData.getPixels(clipRect),width,height,true);
```

I want to make the white color in the generated PNG transparent. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close :)

You need to tell the bitmapData to be transparent, and then fill it with all transparent pixels.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0);
```

(the 0 is shorthand for 0x00000000 which is a 32 bit ARGB color expressed as a uint)

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I had the same question recently and here's what the adobe AS3 reference said: "To create a fully transparent bitmap, set the value of the transparent parameter to true and the value of the fillColor parameter to 0x00000000 (or to 0). "

Comment: yup :) Again, sorry for responding to such an old post.